# Silverstripe GraphQL error after injecting the Member class and adding a custom Member class

Tags: graphql, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I need to override the onBeforeWrite function in the member class in order to allow users who already have an account to be registered. So I defined an Injector in the yml file to the Member class and added a custom member class which extends the Member class. It worked and the function is overridden but now when I'm running the dev/build after it completes there is an GraphQl error shown in the dev build and the graph generated files are also not created.

**injectors.yml code:**

```
SilverStripe\Core\Injector\Injector:
  SilverStripe\Security\Member:
    class: RM\Extension\CustomMember
```

**CustomMember class - **

```
<?php

namespace RM\Extension;

use SilverStripe\Security\Member;
class CustomMember extends Member
{
    public function onBeforeWrite()
    {

        die('reached custom');
        
    }
}
```

The die statement was executed when I'm trying to create an account. So the function is overridden correctly but I get the error (screenshot attached) in the dev build -
[error snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vM9y8.png)

Comment: I think the easiest way to resolve this is actually to just not subclass `Member`. Is the problem that you want multiple `Member` records set up with the same email address? If so, just change the value of the `Member.unique_identifier_field` configuration property. You'll need to do that for authentication to work anyway.